# Create save and close new workbooks with a list of names

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of future names for 83 workbooks that I want to create.
The list is in the first column of a workbook "casenames".

Here is the code that I'm using, but it gives me an error.

```
Sub createworkbook()

Dim casenames As Workbook
Dim ptnames(82) As String
Const FPath As String = ""

Set casenames = Workbooks.Open("")

``For i = 1 To 83
    Workbooks.Add (FPath & casenames.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text & ".xlsx")
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub``
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the names into an array, and then loop over the array.

Also, you can't add a new workbook with a name, you must add the workbook, then save it with the name you want, then close it.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub createworkbook()

    Dim casenames As Workbook
    Dim ptnames As Variant
    Const FPath As String = "C:\temp\"

    'Disable the calculation and screenupdating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assume the casenames workbook is already open
    Set casenames = Workbooks("casenames.xlsx")
    ptnames = casenames.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A83").Value


    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ptnames, 1) To UBound(ptnames, 1)
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
        wbk.SaveAs FPath & ptnames(i, 1) & ".xlsx"
        wbk.Close
    Next i

    'Reinstate the calculation and screenupdating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but I still don't understand why you use:

Comment: `Set wbk = Workbooks.Add`

Comment: and then 
`wbk.SaveAs FPath & ptnames(i, 1) & ".xlsx"`
why can't you just say `Workbooks.Add` and then `Workbooks.SaveAs`

Comment: The `Add` method returns a reference to the workbook that was added, and avoids me *assuming* that the `ActiveWorkbook` is the one I want to save and close.